# How can I apply the function get_publication_abstract from scholar package to the inteire data frame?

Tags: google-scholar

I'm trying to apply the get_publication_abstract function to a data frame at once, but I receive an error that says "Only one ID at a time". My data frame has the author's ID and the ID of the text for each row. I already tried using the apply function, but the same error occurs. How can I get the abstracts for each text in my data frame at once?